# Python: convert json loads to panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I am converting json format into Pandas dataframe but unable to return in table format.
[image]

```
HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
           "Origin": "https://www2.sgx.com",
           "Referer": "https://www2.sgx.com/securities/securities-prices"}

# Start downloading stocks info from sgx
req = requests.get("https://api.sgx.com/securities/v1.1?excludetypes=bonds&params=nc,adjusted-vwap,b,bv,p,c,change_vs_pc,change_vs_pc_percentage,cx,cn,dp,dpc,du,ed,fn,h,iiv,iopv,lt,l,o,p_,pv,ptd,s,sv,trading_time,v_,v,vl,vwap,vwap-currency",
                   headers=HEADERS)
stocks = json.loads(req.text)
table = pd.DataFrame(stocks)
```

n is company

nc is code

lt is price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, `stocks['data']['prices']` is a list of dictionnaries and you only want to keep the `nc`, `n` and `lt` fields in columns names `Code`, `Company` and `Price`.

To build a DataFrame with that, you can do:

```
columns = ['nc', 'n', 'lt']

df = pd.DataFrame([{k: v for k,v in d.items() if k in columns}
               for d in stocks['data']['prices']], columns = columns)
df.rename(columns = {'n': 'Company', 'nc': 'Code', 'lt': 'Price'}, inplace = True)
```

You will get a datframe of 1042 rows and the 3 expected columns... except that the `Company` column will only contain `NaN`value because the original json has no data in `n` field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this, the data is inside the `stocks['data']['prices']`

```
table = pd.DataFrame(stocks['data']['prices'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(stocks)
```